# Error with Calendar after addition and then converting to date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have the following JAVA code

```
public static String getstartDateEvent (int addDay) {
   Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
   today.add(Calendar.DATE,addDay);
   int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   int day = today.get(Calendar.DATE);
   Date date = new Date(year - 1900, month, day); 
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
   String fileDate = formatter.format(date);        
   return fileDate;
   }
```

---

After I run the code I get the following error:

Exception occurred during playback of script [TestScripts.Test_applications] [CRFCN0019E: RationalTestScriptException on line 0 of script TestScripts.BlankScript - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date.].

---

I need help checking the method, I have a main script calling this method, where addDay
need the ability to change. The return is needed because in the main script it sents the date to another method. I am using the script for test automation

---

Update

I trying to have a automated date insert into the code so today is 10/21/2011 and I need to automatically change the date of the maybe 27 days later. In the calendar method the ability to change the format is not avaibable and in the date method there is no option to do an addition to the current date.

Comment: It's not clear why you're extracting the fields anyway... why not just use `formatter.format(today.getTime())`? It's also unclear *what* is failing here. What is your test code doing?

Comment: What has this got to do with functional programming?

Comment: it was supposed to say rational functional tester the program I am using from IBM. I did an update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to

- use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)
- return a `Date[Time/Midnight]` instead of a `String`